# "Coveo.UI.Components.Models.IBaseComponentProperties.Id" is not supported by "SitecoreIdMapper"

Tags: coveo

I'm new to Coveo and it's integration into Sitecore. We're currnently in the process of upgrading a 9.2 instance to 10.3. The search was working, but was missing a few things when we compared with the existing production we're wanting to replace. We suspect the client has not provided us the latest repo, as we're missing a lot of little code pieces.

In my travels of setting up my local I didn't have coveo configured at all, and the search component in the header looked like this.

[image]

After I installed the Coveo package. "Coveo for Sitecore 10.3 5.0.1277.4.zip" provided by our MVP. I then needed to authorize the account and create a trial enterprise subscription for my local instance.

All this worked fine, but when I navigated back to the website. The failing component now looked as it was entended, and showed a search icon with search input. As soon as I attempted to search, I got this error YSOD show up. I'm not sure where to start here.
[image]
\Views\Coveo Hive\Sections\Results Header Section.cshtml    Line: 5

From my understanding this is an out-of-box component that comes from the package. So, I navigated to the Coveo Diagnostic page and it states the versions are compatible.

[image]

Does anyone know what would be causing this? Have you seen it before?
Where should I start looking?

Cheers

EDIT:
Here is the stacktrace of the error, and it seems to be related to GlassMapper.

Full Stack Trace:

```
[NotSupportedException: The type Coveo.UI.Components.Models.IBaseComponentProperties on Coveo.UI.Components.Models.IBaseComponentProperties.Id is not supported by SitecoreIdMapper]
   Glass.Mapper.Sc.DataMappers.SitecoreIdMapper.Setup(DataMapperResolverArgs args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\DataMappers\SitecoreIdMapper.cs:66
   Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.DataMapperResolver.Tasks.DataMapperStandardResolverTask.Execute(DataMapperResolverArgs args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\DataMapperResolver\Tasks\DataMapperStandardResolverTask.cs:30
   Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.c__DisplayClass9_1.b__1(T args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:55
   Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:33
   Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.DataMapperResolver.Tasks.DataMapperAttributeResolverTask.Execute(DataMapperResolverArgs args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\DataMapperResolver\Tasks\DataMapperAttributeResolverTask.cs:34
   Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(T args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:65
   Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.Run(T args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:77
   Glass.Mapper.Context.ProcessProperties(IEnumerable`1 properties) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Context.cs:204
   Glass.Mapper.Context.Load(IConfigurationLoader[] loaders) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Context.cs:176
   Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ConfigurationResolver.Tasks.OnDemandResolver.ConfigurationOnDemandResolverTask`1.Execute(ConfigurationResolverArgs args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ConfigurationResolver\Tasks\OnDemandResolver\ConfigurationOnDemandResolverTask.cs:26
   Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.c__DisplayClass9_1.b__1(T args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:55
   Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:33
   Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Execute(T args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:27
   Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ConfigurationResolver.Tasks.StandardResolver.ConfigurationStandardResolverTask.Execute(ConfigurationResolverArgs args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ConfigurationResolver\StandardResolver\ConfigurationStandardResolverTask.cs:23
   Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.c__DisplayClass9_1.b__1(T args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:55
   Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:33
   Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Execute(T args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:27
   Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.ConfigurationResolver.TemplateInferredTypeTask.Execute(ConfigurationResolverArgs args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\Pipelines\ConfigurationResolver\TemplateInferredTypeTask.cs:60
   Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.c__DisplayClass9_1.b__1(T args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:55
   Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Next(T args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:33
   Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask`1.Execute(T args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineTask.cs:27
   Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.ConfigurationResolver.SitecoreItemResolverTask.Execute(ConfigurationResolverArgs args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\Pipelines\ConfigurationResolver\SitecoreItemResolverTask.cs:36
   Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(T args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:65
   Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.Run(T args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:77
   Glass.Mapper.AbstractService.RunConfigurationPipeline(AbstractTypeCreationContext abstractTypeCreationContext) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\AbstractService.cs:163
   Glass.Mapper.AbstractService.InstantiateObject(AbstractTypeCreationContext abstractTypeCreationContext) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\AbstractService.cs:126
   Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreService.RunCreateType(Item item, GetOptions options, Dictionary`2 parameters) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\SitecoreService.cs:349
   Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreService.GetItem(GetItemOptions options) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\SitecoreService.cs:338
   Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.Response.GetModelFromView.GetDataSourceItem(GetModelArgs args, Type modelType) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc\Pipelines\Response\GetModelFromView.cs:174
   Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.Response.GetModelFromView.Process(GetModelArgs args) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc\Pipelines\Response\GetModelFromView.cs:82
   (Object , Object ) +54
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args, Func`2 resultGetter) +161
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.GetModel() +316
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.get_Model() +31
   Sitecore.Mvc.Extensions.ObjectExtensions.ValueOrDefault(T source, Func`2 resultGetter) +51
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.get_Model() +163
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +160
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check this? https://connect.coveo.com/s/question/0D56Q000085b2q4SAA/coveo-searchbox-not-working-after-upgrade-from-coveo-for-sitecore-41-to-50cloud

Comment: All the stack traces and error messages should be provided as text, not as screenshots

Comment: @GauravAgarwal I had a look, I believe that person is stuck on something else. I have the search box displaying fine, the error shows once I press enter, and search.

Comment: @MarekMusielak I have added the full stack track to the post now.

Comment: @MarekMusielak If you're going to close the question, at least suggest where I can go to ask the question. Absolutely not helpful at all. Meant to be supporting the community here.

Comment: @Anthony I wrote in my comment why I close the question - Stack traces, code blocks and error messages should all be included as snippets. Sitecore Stack Exchange messages can be confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I peeked into the `Coveo.UI.Components.Models.IBaseComponentProperty` and noticed `Id` was a `string`, and GlassMapper uses reflection to work out where to send the code for processing.

[image: Coveo.UI.Components.Models.IBaseComponentProperty]

When I looked at the `Glass.Mapper.Sc.DataMappers.SitecoreIdMapper` I can see it trying to look for a type of ID or GUID. Since it was forced to be a string, it would throw the NotSupportedException. So the answer was to parse the ID type with custom code between these 2 libraries, and making sure it was a type of GUID. Unfortunately, the location of this custom code will differ per-project. So if you get this error, you'll need to work out where they talk and put that parse code in (`new Guid(IBaseComponentProperty.Id);`).

[image]

Hope that helps.